# Mapping the WebDynpro Application to the sap UI5 Application?

Tags: sapui5

I have developed Web Dynpro application and the same needs to be mapped in UI5 application as a new Tab .

Any suggestions to make it cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could add a frame to an existing UI5 Application in a new tab, but the Fiori guidelines would suggest that you'd create the WebDynpro a new tile rather than a tab on an existing application.